# Make joints colliders

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have made a dynamically changing shape (blob) out of multiple nodes and distance joints.  I would like to know how I can make the distance joints collide with the outside world.  The nodes are just box2d circles and they already collide however an object can freely pass through the spring like distance joint connecting the multiple circles. How can I stop objects from passing through the distance joints or even the distance joints from comming in contact with eachother? Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it. Joints do not collide. Only bodies with shapes attached to them collide in box2d